# how to create a friendship model on Rails 5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm new to rails and I'm trying to create a friendship model where user receive notifications and can accept or decline friendships. I have found similar versions of it but must of them for rails 3 or before, I was wondering if there is some material that I could look at for the current version.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the  ['has_friendship' gem](https://github.com/sungwoncho/has_friendship) for this.

This gem is really simple to use

1. Create the migration `rails generate has_friendship`
2. Add to the model

   ```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_friendship
   end
   ```
3. and you can start to manage your friends

Managing friendship

```
# Create Friends 
@joe = User.create(name: "Joe")
@doe = User.create(name: "Doe")

# @joe sends a friend request to @doe
@joe.friend_request(@doe)

# @doe can accept the friend request
@doe.accept_request(@joe)

# @doe can also decline the friend request
@doe.decline_request(@joe)

# @doe removes @joe from its friends
@doe.remove_friend(@joe)
```

again you can find more info on the gem Documention site https://github.com/sungwoncho/has_friendship

I hope that this helps :)